¿Cómo insertar un marcador utilizando Jinja 2 en Word y Python?
Actualmente este es mi código de python:
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
cliente = "123"
tablas = []
tabla1 = [['Nombre Empresa', 'Suma de Monto', 'Cuenta de Monto2', 'Suma de Monto2'], ['Empresa A', 1928751.87, 44.0, 0.9616609401755635]]
tabla2 = [['Nombre Empresa', 'Suma de Monto', 'Cuenta de Monto2', 'Suma de Monto2'], ['Empresa B', 1928751.87, 44.0, 0.9616609401755635]]
tabla1 = tabla1[1:]
tabla2 = tabla2[1:]
tablas.append((tabla1, tabla2))
tabla1 = [['Nombre Empresa', 'Suma de Monto', 'Cuenta de Monto2', 'Suma de Monto2'], ['Empresa A', 76894.6, 207.0, 0.03833905982443656]]
tabla2 = [['Nombre Empresa', 'Suma de Monto', 'Cuenta de Monto2', 'Suma de Monto2'], ['Empresa B', 76894.6, 207.0, 0.03833905982443656]]
tabla1 = tabla1[1:]
tabla2 = tabla2[1:]
tablas.append((tabla1, tabla2))
print(tablas)
doc=DocxTemplate('Plantilla.docx')

for tabla1, tabla2 in tablas:
    print(f"Tabla 1:\n{tabla1}")
    print(f"Tabla 2:\n{tabla2}")
    context={
        'tablas': tablas,
        'tabla1': tabla1,
        'tabla2': tabla2,
        'ncuenta': nroCuenta
    }
    doc.render(context)
doc.save("Plantilla_llenada.docx")

En Plantilla.docx tengo lo siguiente:
{% for tabla1, tabla2 in tablas %}
{% set iterador = loop.index %}
1.  Información del cliente N°{{ cliente}} ():

{{ 'tabla_' + iterador|string }}

{% endfor %}

Al ejecutar el código de python obtengo el siguiente word Plantilla_llenada.docx, que contiene lo siguiente:
1.  Información del cliente N°123 ():

tabla_1
2.  Información del cliente N°123 ():

tabla_2

Entonces, mi pregunta es cómo insertar un marcador donde estan posicionados tabla_1 y tabla2 con el mismo nombre. El word deberia quedar asi:
1.  Información del cliente N°123 ():

("Aquí debe estar insertado el marcador de nombre "tabla_1"")
2.  Información del cliente N°123 ():
("Aquí debe estar insertado el marcador de nombre "tabla_2"")

